# output list of files from popen to ifstream.open

Tags: c++, popen, ifstream

Basically I need to open and read a list of files I get from another command.
For each line of output of popen
 open a file usen ifstream.open

it compiles and if I put the file name directly it works fine, but it doesn't do anything when using popen output. I've seen questions like this but none of this particular way of giving filenames.

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main () {

    ifstream singlefile;
    FILE *filelist;
    char filename[512];
    string progline;

    if(!(filelist = popen("find `pwd` -name \"*.js\"", "r"))){
        return 1;
    }

    while( fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), filelist)!=NULL)
    {
        cout << filename;
        singlefile.open(filename, ifstream::in);
        while ( singlefile.good() )
        {
            getline (singlefile,progline);
            cout << progline << endl;
        }

        singlefile.close();
    }

    pclose(filelist);

  return 0;

}
```

next step would be not open each file inside the loop but to store the file list and then open each file.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using the `find` utility through `popen()` instead of something more lightweight like [`scandir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scandir)?

Comment: @AndréCaron: `scandir` is not part of the C standard.  In any case, for C++ I'd suggest [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm).

Comment: @Philipp: `popen()` is not part of the C standard either.  I only recommended something *more lightweight like* `scandir()`.  `Boost.Filesystem` is definitely an option.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Oops, I somehow got the impression `popen` were standard C (because it returns a `FILE*`).

Comment: this is one shot program, and picked using c++ and not awk or even python to get into c++. I'm reading about boost because of the regex so I may check the filesystem interface too. Thanks for your comments. Got even more than I needed. Happy coding!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` keeps the trailing newline, resulting in a filename of a non-existing file.  Also the stream state is only updated after reading.  If I replace the `while` body with the following code, it works for me:

```
  cout << filename;
  size_t len = strlen(filename);
  // chop off trailing newline
  if (len > 1 && filename[len - 1] == '\n') filename[len - 1] = 0;
  singlefile.open(filename, ifstream::in);
  while ( getline(singlefile, progline) )
    {
      cout << progline << endl;
    }

  singlefile.close();
```

---

If you actually want to iterate through a list of files, I'd use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm), which has a nice C++ interface, works for all filenames (even for those with newlines), and is platform-independent.

If this actually is only an example and your actual command is not `find`, there is still some room for simplification.  Here is a suggestion that uses [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) to get rid of most of the C function calls (it would be great to have a device source reading from a process's standard output, but Boost.Iostreams lacks that):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

class Popen: private boost::noncopyable {
public:
  explicit Popen(const char* command):
    m_stream(popen(command, "r")) {
    if (!m_stream) throw runtime_error("popen failed");
  }

  ~Popen() {
    pclose(m_stream);
  }

  FILE* stream() const {
    return m_stream;
  }

private:
  FILE* m_stream;
};


int main() {
  Popen pipe_wrapper("find `pwd` -name \"*.cpp\"");
  io::file_descriptor_source pipe_device(fileno(pipe_wrapper.stream()), io::never_close_handle);
  io::stream<io::file_descriptor_source> pipe_stream(pipe_device, 0x1000, 0x1000);
  string filename;
  while (getline(pipe_stream, filename)) {
    cout << filename << endl;
    ifstream file_stream(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);
    string progline;
    while (getline(file_stream, progline)) {
      cout << progline << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: exactly! addin filename[strlen(filename)-1]=0; before opening the file did the trick. thanks for the extra info.